# Trigger logout.html page on clicking Logout in angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I am working on logout functionality. On click of logout button which is kept in the navigation bar . I should open logout .html which contains a message saying that the user logged out now. I was able to achieve this but the navigation bar is still there . I am calling logout component using **ui-sref**.

Appreciate your help in guiding me to show just logout.html without the navigation bar.

```
import UiRouterModule = require('angular-ui-router');
import * as angular from 'angular';

const mod = angular.module('logout.routing', [
<any>UiRouterModule
]);

const moduleName = mod.name;

mod.config(($stateProvider) => {
$stateProvider
.state('logout', {
url: '/logout',
template: `<logout></logout>`
});
});

export { moduleName as LogoutRoutingModule };
```

Comment: do you use the router?

Comment: code please....?

Comment: Added my router comment

Comment: Cant you directly use href ?

Comment: @RaviRajput I tried.  It  was not working . So I went ahead adding logout component

Comment: @Edison added .

Comment: are you building single page application????

Comment: @RaviRajput yes

Comment: what about `*ngIf="showTopbar"` and route as `{
    path: '/logOut',
    name: 'logOut',
    data: {
        hideTopbar: true,
        hideSidebar: true
    }
},`

Comment: @Edison I think this Implementation should work.  But how can I get the hidetopbar value from logout module .